# Jquery - is it possible to bind css hover/focus behaviours to keydown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope I can be succinct with my question.

Lets say I have some css defined.

```
.someCSS-name:hover > .list-item,
.someCSS-name:active > .list-item,
.someCSS-name:focus > .list-item { display:block; }
```

Now, in my jquery code how can I create or possible bind a tab press with that css above. Sorta have the tab keypress inherit that css behaviour?

Perhaps I am overthinking it here.

```
<li class="someCSS-name" id="linkoneli">
    <a href="someURL" id="linkonenav">Link One</a>
    <div class="list-item">show this content</div>
</li>
```

That is a snippet, basically a user tabs on that link - and I have a popup that shows.. but instead of explicitly eventHandling and poping it etc.. I was hoping that i could use my CSS to somehow become binded to my tab/keypress.. possible? So a tab would be the same as 'hover' etc..

Comment: Try to add `tabindex` to your li: http://jsfiddle.net/kXWUZ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if you use a css selector on anchor element focus state, you will achieve that effect. Here is the snippet you might need.

```
#linkonenav:focus ~ .list-item {
  display: block;
}
```

jsFiddle just to try http://jsfiddle.net/greenrobo/eLCmM/

Comment: `~` and `+` in a css selector will select the siblings of an element. `~` is [General Sibling Selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) and `+` is [Adjacent Sibling Selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector).

Comment: I like this. Will it only work in certain browsers. Also, can you use it like so: .some-selector-css:focus ~ > .second-selector {display: block}  ---> I just didn't understand "why" tab would work in this case. thanks.

Comment: `+` is available from CSS2, while `~` is from CSS3. All the major browsers will support both as CSS3 is much popular now. You can check the browser compatibility in the links provided above.

I think you can't use `.some-selector-css:focus ~ > .second-selector {display: block}` as there are two consecutive symbol selectors (`>` and `~`). I would suggest to do it like this
`.some-selector-css:focus ~ .sib > .second-selector {display: block}`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to just toggle .someCSS on keypress so

```
$('.myElements').toggleClass('someCSS');
```

If that will turn on/off the hovering css. If you just want to toggle whatever style the hover turns on and off, just move those style to an .active class and toggle that class instead so

```
$('.someCSS').toggleClass('.active');
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply - yeah, this is what I was referring to as having to work thru the tabing order and such and do what you have above. I might have to use this. But i was hoping there was some jquery way to do something like : jQuery.inherit('focus',.SomeCSS-name, 'tab') .. hahah. wishful thinking on my part.

Comment: there might be some secret voodoo, but I think javascript/css events are separate. I don't know of any way one can trigger the other.